# Is it possible to override http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a widget that I've built that can be embedded anywhere on the web. I've noticed a problem with it on sites that use `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"` in their header.

This is because I'm using modern javascript which IE7 does not handle well.

Is it possible to override this somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by "override"? IE has their F12 developer tools and you can change what mode the browser runs in. That http-equiv header or meta tag is added by the document owner to indicate its level of compliance with IE versions. If you change that, sure, your widget would look great, but the rest of page might break.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

If someone has `content=IE7` meta tag in their site, then it means that they know that their site does not work in more modern versions of IE. They've specified it explicitly, so they obviously meant it.

You can't override this from within your script, and even if you could, what good would it do? You'd break the rest of the site for their sake of making your widget work.

The best you could do is add code to your widget to detect the browser mode or the detect whether features you need are available, and pop an error message into your widget if not so that the owner of the site can see it immediately.

Comment: Yeah that's been taken into consideration, and I understand it. This is such an edge case, their site works fine when not in IE7 mode, but you're right. "Fixing" this one issue would more than likely cause many more.

The problem is that unfortunately there are no features that we can bring down to IE7 compatibility. IE8 we can deal with, IE7 we cannot.

Comment: No, I appreciate that. And to be honest, it's the people who are using IE7 mode who need to sort it out and stop relying on the busted old compatibility mode -- if they don't do something about it now, they are going to crash and burn when they upgrade to Win10 and find that the Edge browser doesn't have compatibility modes any more.